# Send datatable as parameter to rdlc report and view it in the report body

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have .rdlc report as follows:

[image]

I am filling purchase order details normally from database. But I need to fill purchased items details from datatable that should be sent as parameter to the report in runtime.

Can you please show me how to send datatable as parameter and how to show its contents in rdlc report? I am using asp.net and c#

Comment: have you created any dataset inside report?

Comment: only xsd dataset from which I get data from database.  But I need to fill other information from datatable which is created in runtime and show it in the report.

Comment: are you using a report viewer control in local processing mode?

Comment: yes I am using local report